# Understanding how different companies interpret VDA5050 standards and how is this resolved

Tags: navigation

I've been researching the VDA5050 standard, particularly in the context of robotic intercommunication for AMRs and AGVs, as part of a college project. I have a background in grid navigation-based AGVs from my previous internship, where we used different methods to prevent deadlocks, such as locking nodes and unidirectional graphs. However, VDA5050 seems to address the intercommunication aspect I'm interested in.

My question revolves around the practical implementation of VDA5050. Given the potential for differing interpretations and strategies among companies when it comes to issues like when a robot should unlock a node it has traversed, I wonder how this standard handles potential ambiguities and differences in perspectives. Are there established mechanisms or best practices to address such incidents in the real world?

Also having some sort of example simulation which uses the concepts of VDA5050 would be really helpful in gaining some perspective on this problem.

Thank you for your insights and time.

Comment: This question would be better suited as a forum discussion topic, rather than here, where we tend to focus on specific problems.  You can check [this](https://discourse.ros.org/t/vda5050-interface-for-ros-2/31609) post for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Given the potential for differing interpretations and strategies among companies when it comes to issues like when a robot should unlock a node it has traversed, I wonder how this standard handles potential ambiguities and differences in perspectives.

This functionality is handled by a Master Controller, AFAIK. The standard communicates what information *(order/instantAction)* would be sent to the robot, and in what format. The orders and their meanings should be agreed upon by the robot and the master controller. So, when we send a "pick" order to a robot, it is assumed that the robot knows that for picking the object, it would need to navigate to the location of that object, and pick it. This allows robot vendors to design around the specifications, and provide custom behaviours when needed.

> My question revolves around the practical implementation of VDA5050.

A general implementation involves the design of an interface layer, which takes in VDA5050 commands, interprets them according to the robot's capabilities, and sends the necessary commands to the robot to execute the order. If we take an example of an automated forklift, if we send a VDA5050 "pick" order to it, this order is received by the forklift, where it might be parsed as:

- Go to the position $(x, y, theta)$
- Lower the fork to its lowest position
- Move forward
- Lift the fork to a higher position
- Move out of the picking zone

The robot would then receive these actions in a sequence, and execute them one by one, providing feedback to the higher-level interface layer which relays the information over to the Master controller.

> Also having some sort of example simulation which uses the concepts of VDA5050 would be really helpful in gaining some perspective on this problem.

You can check out [this](https://github.com/inorbit-ai/vda5050_adapter_examples) example and [this](https://discourse.ros.org/t/isaac-mission-dispatch-client-w-vda5050-open-source-release-for-ros2/27856) post where you have implementations of the VDA5050 standard, but this is highly focused on ROS 2. If you are not using ROS 2, you can take inspiration from these posts and develop your own interface layer for your custom stack.